# WordPress MU Domain Mapping Redirect Loop

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

I’m not sure if I’m going about this the right way. I need to have multiple domains pointed to a sub site on a network.

Basically example.com and sub.example2.com and not have sub.example2.com just redirect to example.com

Plugin config:

Domain Options
Remote Login – Off

Permanent redirect (better for your blogger’s page rank) – Off

User domain mapping page – On

Redirect administration pages to site’s original domain (remote login disabled if this redirect is disabled) – Off

Disable primary domain check. Sites will not redirect to one domain name. May cause duplicate content issues. – On

The problem I’m having is that sub.example2.com has a redirect loop and I’m not sure why.

Would anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Not a direct answer but pointers to help debug

First off the [domain mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin is [no longer needed](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/) since WP 4.x
I recommend turning the plugin off and removing `sunrise` from in `wp-config.php`

To check if the redirect is caused by WP try to visit a static file on all domains. Like `/readme.html` and `/license.txt`.
If these static files are also redirected the problem is the webserver, check hosting stettings and `.htaccess`

home and rewrite pages that are handled by WP and it's rewrite rules

Check in the `wp_blogs` table what url is set. also check the `wp_options` tables of each site for the `home` and `siteurl`.

In the `wp-config.php` you could also set urls check `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`, `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL`

If you make changes remember to flush the rewrite rules (just save the permalinks any site).

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! But without the plugin can I have two domains used for one site on the network?

Comment: Yes check the [no longer needed](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/howto-domain-mapping-without-a-plugin-instructions/) link

Comment: Thank you. I don't see where it says I can set up 2 domains for 1 sub site. Where in that link should I be looking?

Comment: just don't think of it as a subdomain. _sub.example2.com_ just view that as a full domain (which it technically is). step 7 does mention this kind of setup

Comment: Not sure if you are getting what I need to do. I need a subsite to have two domains routed to it not just 1.

Comment: 1 subsite have 2 domains? That's the complete opposite from what I was thinking, sorry. If it's possible at all it will be hard. WP identifies the current subsite based on the doemina.

Comment: No worries! That's why I'm using the plugin as it makes it possible but it's just bugging out. It works if the second domain is just redirected but I need the masking method work instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194525/discussion-between-janw-and-barrywalsh).